# Saving large files in h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, h2, h2db

I recently updated the h2 database in my springboot project to 2.1.210.

This induced some problems, most of them I was able to fix myself. The one that I can't fix is about saving large files in the database.

When I try to upload a ~3,5MB file, I get following error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: 
Value too long for column "BINARY VARYING": "504b03040a00000000008a6bd150e8d6354d8303010083030100070000003030302e706e6789504e... (3648495)" [22001-210]
```

The annotation, which worked flawlessly on h2 1.4.200 looks like this

```
@Lob
@Type( type = "binary" )
@Column(name = "ZIP", columnDefinition="BLOB")
private byte[] zip;
```

I don't know if its related, but I also get an error when using

```
@Type( type = "text" )
```

The error here is

```
Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1048576" inclusive
```

because whenever I use "text", it gets translated to `varchar(2147483647)`

Comment: This problem should be fixed with version 2.1.212.
See https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3457
The strange thing is: With the newer version, my binary type (@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")) is stored as varbinary (with 1.X versions it was of type binary).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, since H2 version 2, the `org.h2.value.Value.getBytes()` method has changed significantly so as to limit the amount that can be held in memory in a byte array.

The H2 manual ([data types](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#binary_large_object_type) and [large objects](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#large_objects)) says that the allowed length is from 1 to 1048576 bytes for BINARY VARYING and for anything else `ResultSet.getBinaryStream(...)` is the preferred method.

I'm not sure how you go about controlling this in HQL or using Hibernate annotations, but changing the data type from `byte[]` to some kind of stream may encourage the ORM to avoid `rs.getBytes(...)` and call H2's favoured method instead.